# Solution stack for BI with Pentaho and web app

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence

My goal is to build web app showing on-line reports and static reports from BI system. I'm thinking about solution stack. At the moment I'm focus on pentaho solutions.

My question are:
It is possible to do this with pentaho CE:
-> Load data by Kettle (ETL process) 
-> analyse it in Pentaho 
-> shows reports in web app and gets data by REST services (similar to this solution: http://www.webdetails.pt/showcase/ ) ?

If is not possible to make with CE version witch product from EE it will be needed?

Or what other technology stack can help me achive my goal??

Comment: Yes Pentaho will solve your queries. You may check [this](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/open-source-bi-stack/). Also i suppose you can also try for PowerBI. Its pretty good but not exactly opensource as a reporting/dashboard solution.